# How to compare timestamp and only print one date if they are the same

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm storing items on firebase and succeed to sort them by expiration date. Date is a timestamp (child expires).

For each product i'm printing the date of expiration date but some products have the same expiration date. Actually if two elements have the same date, i'm printing two times the same date.

How can I compare the date of each product and print only one date if two or more products have the same date ? After that I want my items to be stored under the same day

Here is an exemple of my website : https://nshop-b7557.firebaseapp.com/ (mardi 21 mai for instance)

```
export const actions = {
getProducts ({commit}) {fireApp.database().ref('products').orderByChild('expires').startAt(Date.now() / 1e3).once('value')
  .then(snapShot => {
    const products = []
    let item = {}
    snapShot.forEach(child => {
      item = child.val()
      item.key = child.key
      products.push(item)
    })
    commit('loadProducts', products)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
},
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter the data. Example in javascript: https://codeburst.io/javascript-array-distinct-5edc93501dc4

Answer (score 0):

None if your code is printing products or dates right now. But the solution is typically something like this:

```js
let products = [
  { name: 'product1', date: '20190429' },
  { name: 'product2', date: '20190429' },
  { name: 'product3', date: '20190430' },
  { name: 'product4', date: '20190430' },
  { name: 'product5', date: '20190501' }
];

var last_date;
products.forEach(product => {
  if (product.date != last_date) {
    last_date = product.date;
    console.log(last_date);
  }
  console.log('  '+product.name);
})
```